# ML (NN) model for a physical process (layer movement in ensilage)

Tags: neural-networks, modeling, recurrent-neural-network

The problem is, I have a several silages with several layers of some substance in them (e.g. coal). Each layer has its own physical/chemical properties (concentration of element, X). Concentration of X in each layer is known.
Then we get a mixture of masses W from several (known) silos, and get a concentration of that element in mixture = Xmix.

Mixing of a value X is proportional to masses from each layer Xmix = (w1 * X1 + w2*X2 + w5*X5 + w11*X11) / (w1+w2+w5+w11)

Number of layers differs (usually 1 to 4). Total number of silos o 50.
Which silos are used for each dispense differs.
A new layer in any silo can be added at any time.
There is a model FIFO (first in first out), that is working not very good. According to it, layers in 1 silo get dispensed one by one.

The problem is that in reality layers in silos a mixing (coal in the center drops down much faster than on sides). So when we dispense 100 tons from Silo #1, there may actually be 50 tons from the bottom layer, 20 tons from 2nd, 20 from 3rd and 10 from the 4th layer.
And in the next dispension we will have to start from different masses of each layer.

This looks like a RNN model, but I'm new to NNs and I can't fully figure out, which layers to maka and how to "connect" them.